# Could you help me with this improper integral

Tags: improper-integrals

How can I evaluate this improper integral?

$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx $$

Comment: This doesn't converge.

Comment: Near $x=0$ your function is of the same order as $1/x$, so the left limit of integration is a problem for convergence.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx\geq\int_0^1\frac1{2x}\,dx$$ which is more clearly divergent ($\lim\limits_{t\to0^+}\left[\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)\right]_t^1$).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

$$x=\tan { u } $$ $$dx=\frac { 1 }{ { \left( \cos { u }  \right)  }^{ 2 } } du$$ $$\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ x\left( { x }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  } dx } =\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { \cos { u }  }{ \sin { u }  } du } 
$$

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and it's really easy to see that the integral is divergent.

Comment: you're wellcome.

Answer (score 2):

Help getting started: Start by writing the integral like this:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\; dx = \lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_t^1\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\; dx + \lim_{s\to \infty}\int_1^{s}\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\; dx.
$$
If you can show that one of these integrals is divergent, then the original integral is divergent.

First we can consider the integral 
$$\begin{align}
\int_t^1 \frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\; dx &= \int_t^1 \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{1+x^2}\; dx \\
&= \ln\lvert x\rvert - \frac{1}{2}\ln\lvert 1 + x^2\rvert\left. \right]_t^1\\
&= \ln\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\left.\right]_t^1
\end{align}
$$
I believe that when you evaluate this and take the limit as $t$ goes to $0$ from the right, then is $-\infty$. So yes, the integral is divergent.

But, you should probably check the details.

Comment: Ok, so if I use $ \lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_t^1\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\; dx = \log 1 -\lim_{t\to 0^+}\log x- \frac{1}{2}\log 2 + \frac{1}{2}\log 1 = \infty $ then the original integral is divergent?

Answer (score 1):

An indefinite integral leads to (breaking it into simple fractions) $$log(x)-\frac{1}{2}log(1+x^2)$$ So clearly you have problems at $x=0$.